# R package creation function names and .R/.rd name

Tags: r, function, file, package

Does the name of the .R and .rd files (documentation) need to have the exact same name as the function it refers to?

For example, can I have a function called "b" and another one called "B" within the same R package and write the documentation into different .R and .rd files?

I'm a bit confused and I wasn't able to find someone encountering the same problem (I even looked it up on DataCamp's course), so thanks in advance.

Best regards!

Comment: R is case sensitive, so you _ought to_ be able to do this - either having two functions in the same package named `foo` and `FOO` or two files named `bar.R` or `BAR.R`.  But it sounds like a very bad idea.  Why would you want to have these pairs which differ only on capitalization?

Comment: I know It might seem to be a bad idea but it has to do with the usual way of calling the mathematical functions that I'm trying to replicate in the package, so It would be natural for the user to understand when to use each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the .R file can contain many functions, it doesn't need to have the same exact name as the function(s) it refers to.

Regarding the .Rd files, it's much easier/efficient/practical to let Roxygen turn [specially formatted comments](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) into .Rd files.

On Windows (files not case sensitive) avoid to use Upper case / lower case to distinguish functions, because the .Rd file of one of the functions will be overwritten:

```
Updating package documentation
Loading package
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing FOO.Rd
Writing foo.Rd
```

```
#' foo
#'
#' A function to print bar
#'
#' @param bar 
#'
#' @return prints input
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' foo(1)
#' 
foo <- function(bar) { print(bar) }

#' FOO
#'
#' Another function to print bar
#'
#' @param bar 
#'
#' @return prints input
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' foo(1)
#' 
FOO <- function(bar) { print(bar) }
```

```
?foo
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using roxygen and I've already documented and built the function "b" (I have a .R and .rd file with the name b). 
But when I try to document the B function (the .R file is named B_.R) it won't generate any .rd file and the function won't be built into the package.